# discord.py - How can I make a leaderboard command for levels in a Discord server? (JSON file)

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I have a leveling system for my bot. It works perfectly fine, but I want to know how to make a leaderboard for it. I tried the code shown below from this website:

```
@bot.command()
async def top10(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Top 10 server's leaderboard:", color=discord.Colour.gold())
    with open('level.json', 'r') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
    sorted_data = {id: bal for id, bal in sorted(data.items(), reverse=True ,key=lambda item: item[1])}

    for pos, (id, bal) in enumerate(sorted_data.items()):
        member = ctx.guild.get_member(int(id))
        embed.add_field(name=f"{pos+1} - {member.display_name}", value=f"{bal} accolades", inline=False)
        if pos+1 > 9:
            break 
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

But it just gave me a error saying `Command raised an exception: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'`. The JSON file is for each server, so if a user has level 5 in a server, when they chat in another server, their level in that server is over there. I want it to show the top 10 people who have the most levels from the server id, what level they are, and their XP. The example JSON file is show below right here:

```
{
  "757383943116030074": {
    "123456789012345678": {
      "experience": 0,
      "level": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to make a leaderboard **for the server** and show how much levels and XP they have? Please and thank you.

if you need the **entire** code for the leveling system: here you go ;)

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if not message.author.bot:
        # specify the encoding as utf-8 when opening the file
        with open('level.json','r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        await update_data(users, message.author,message.guild)
        await add_experience(users, message.author, 4, message.guild)
        await level_up(users, message.author,message.channel, message.guild)

        # specify the encoding as utf-8 when writing the file
        with open('level.json','w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)
    await bot.process_commands(message)




async def update_data(users, user,server):
    if not str(server.id) in users:
        users[str(server.id)] = {}
        if not str(user.id) in users[str(server.id)]:
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)] = {}
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['experience'] = 0
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['level'] = 1
    elif not str(user.id) in users[str(server.id)]:
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)] = {}
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['experience'] = 0
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['level'] = 1

async def add_experience(users, user, exp, server):
  users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['experience'] += exp

async def level_up(users, user, channel, server):
  experience = users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['experience']
  lvl_start = users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['level']
  lvl_end = int(experience ** (1/4))
  if str(user.guild.id) != '757383943116030074':
    if lvl_start < lvl_end:
      await channel.send(':fire: {} has leveled up to **Level {}!**'.format(user.mention, lvl_end))
      users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['level'] = lvl_end
      embed=discord.Embed(title=':fire: {} has leveled up to **Level {}!**'.format(user.mention, lvl_end), color=0x38ff6a)
      await bot.get_channel(log_channel_id).send(embed=embed)

@bot.command(aliases = ['rank','lvl'])
async def level(ctx,member: discord.Member = None):
    if not member:
        user = ctx.message.author
        # specify the encoding as utf-8 when opening the file
        with open('level.json','r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['level']
        exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['experience']

        embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Level {}'.format(lvl), description = f"{exp} XP " ,color = discord.Color.green())
        embed.set_author(name = ctx.author, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar.url)
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)
    else:
      # specify the encoding as utf-8 when opening the file
      with open('level.json','r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
          users = json.load(f)
      lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(member.id)]['level']
      exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(member.id)]['experience']
      embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Level {}'.format(lvl), description = f"{exp} XP" ,color = discord.Color.green())
      embed.set_author(name = member, icon_url = member.avatar.url)

      await ctx.send(embed = embed)

@bot.command()
async def top10(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Top 10 server's leaderboard:", color=discord.Colour.gold())
    with open('level.json', 'r') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
    sorted_data = {id: bal for id, bal in sorted(data.items(), reverse=True ,key=lambda item: item[1])}

    for pos, (id, bal) in enumerate(sorted_data.items()):
        member = ctx.guild.get_member(int(id))
        embed.add_field(name=f"{pos+1} - {member.display_name}", value=f"{bal} accolades", inline=False)
        if pos+1 > 9:
            break
```

Comment: Is the first "layer" of dictionnaries the id of the server, and inside is the id of the member, or the other way around?

Comment: i think that's it

Comment: So, you need first access the server data. `data = json.load(f)[str(ctx.guild.id)]`

Comment: i did the thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of issues. Firstly, you need to work with the member data, which is one level down in the JSON, so you need

```py
data = data[str(ctx.guild.id)]
```

after you load the JSON.

Secondly, you want to sort on the `level` value in the member data, so you need to specify that to the sort function.

```py
sorted_data = sorted(data.items(), key = lambda item:item[1]['level'], reverse=True)
```

Note there is no need to use a dict comprehension here, you can just call `sorted` directly to get a list of sorted values, and change your `for` statement to match:

```py
for pos, (id, bal) in enumerate(sorted_data):
```

Finally, you probably want to print a value from the member data rather than the object, so you might want something like:

```py
embed.add_field(name=f"{pos+1} - {member.display_name}", value=f"{bal['level']} accolades", inline=False)
```

So in total, your code should look something like:

```py
@bot.command()
async def top10(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Top 10 server's leaderboard:", color=discord.Colour.gold())
    with open('level.json', 'r') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
    data = data[str(ctx.guild.id)]
    sorted_data = sorted(data.items(), key = lambda item:item[1]['level'], reverse=True)

    for pos, (id, bal) in enumerate(sorted_data):
        member = ctx.guild.get_member(int(id))
        embed.add_field(name=f"{pos+1} - {member.display_name}", value=f"{bal['level']} accolades", inline=False)
        if pos+1 > 9:
            break 
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```